# Python Make dict of lists from string

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have the dict of lists that stored in database as a text

```
a = {u'1': [u'12'], u'2': [u'7', u'8', u'9']}
```

I want manipulating with this structure as a dict of lists.

```
a["2"][3] = 9
```

but haven't any idea how to convert this string to dict of lists back.

Comment: Is `a = {u'1': [u'12'], u'2': [u'7', u'8', u'9']}` the text that you actually store in your database?

Comment: No, apparently I'm wrong. The solution you accepted stores it as JSON whereas your question shows a form roughly equivalent to `repr(a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store that data as JSON rather than just the repr of a dict. Then you can easily convert to and from that format using the `json` library.

Comment: Tnx. I can do what I want using JSON
`a = {u'1': [u'12'], u'2': [u'7', u'8', u'9']}`
Make JSON
`y = json.dumps(a)
b = json.loads(y)`

`>>> b["2"][1]
8`

Answer (score 0):

Tnx. I can do what I want using JSON

```
import json    
a = {u'1': [u'12'], u'2': [u'7', u'8', u'9']}
```

Make JSON

```
y = json.dumps(a) 
b = json.loads(y)
```

And finally we have

```
>>> b["2"][1]
8
```